# Windows Service not showing up in Services

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

I created a Windows Service and a setup project.
When I installed the service using the setup installer it is properly installed on the system.

But I didn't see my service in the Services window. I gave all the right permissions, I tried to delete the setup and recreated the new setup still it didn't work.
I tried manually installing using Install Util.exe using the following command

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe  C:\myproject\project1\bin\project1.exe
```

Still it didn't install properly... My system is Windows7 64 bit and VS2010
Is this because of 64 bit system?

Comment: Did you run the code to create the service as administrator, or with UAC off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an installer class to your project.  Once you have the installer class added you need to add a  serviceInstaller and a serviceProcessInstaller to the installer class.  You then use these to give your service a display name, install name, etc.  I'm surprised the installutil.exe worked without this stuff already setup.